# Adding Win32 application to Windows Autoplay menu (for a specific kind of media)?

Tags: c++, windows, autoplay

How can I add my Windows application (written in C++) to the Windows AutoPlay menu for a specific kind of media?

Answer (score 1):

(Notice: I have never tried to do this)

AutoPlay only recognizes three types of media (pictures, music, video) and I don't think there is any way to add another type.  It can recognize many different devices.  You can register for events based on media or device type.  Partial instructions are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  That link doesn't describe how to actually define the handler though, but that doesn't look too hard.  The handlers are defined in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\Handlers
```

There's a bunch in there already that you can use as examples.